Does a 2d random walk hit 0 for increasing distances AND time spans?
Question: For a simple symmetric random walk $(Z_t)_{t\geq 0}$ in $\mathbb{Z}^2$, does
$$\lim_{\beta\rightarrow 0}\mathbb{P}^{x_\beta}(Z_t=0\text{ for some }t\leq h(\beta)T)=0\quad (2.8)$$
where $|x_\beta|>\sqrt{\beta^{-1}}(\log(\beta^{-1}))^{-1}$ and $h(\beta)=\beta^{-1}\log(\beta^{-1})$ and $T>0$?
Background: This is equation (2.8) on p. 9 in this paper.
However, I doubt their proof (and haven't found any other source for their claim):
First, they show that $A(S_{n\wedge \tau_0})$ is a martingale, where $S_n$ is a simple symmetric random walk in discrete time (unlike $Z_t$), $\tau_0$ is the hitting time for 0 and $A(x)\sim \frac{2}{\pi}\ln|x|+O(1)$ the potential kernel in $d=2$.
Second, they consider $\alpha(\beta)$, namely...

the probability that the random walk started in $x_\beta$ hits the ball of radius $2K$ before it exits the ball of radius $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\beta}}\log(\beta^{-1})$.

(the constant $2K$ is nowhere defined, I guess $0<2K<|x_\beta|$)
By applying the optional stopping theorem to $a(S_{n\wedge \tau_0})$ they show that...

$\alpha(\beta)$ converges to 0 as $\beta\rightarrow 0$. This proves (2.8).

(How) Does $\alpha(\beta)\rightarrow 0$ imply (2.8)?
Any opinion or comment is welcomed! (and strongly encouraged:)
